# How to align multiple eqnarrays?

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment

I tried to created 2 `eqnarray`s but the equations in those 2 `eqnarray`s don't line up together.  Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\begin{document}
\begin{eqnarray}
\label{eq1}
&& diag\frac{\partial P}{\partial \theta}= 
diag(-diag(V)[Gdiag(V)\sin(Abus)^{T}-Bdiag(V)cos(Abus)^{T}]
\nonumber\\
&& -diag(V).^{2}diag(diag(B))))  \\
\label{eq2}
&& nondiag\frac{\partial P}{\partial \theta}= 
VV^{T}.* G .* \sin(Abus) -VV^{T}.*B .* \cos(Abus)   
\end{eqnarray}
Replace the diagnol elements of the (\ref{eq2}) with the elements of the                
(\ref{eq1}), we will get the complete $\partial P/\partial \theta$
\begin{eqnarray}
\label{eq3}
&& diag\frac{\partial P}{\partial V}=
diag(Gdiag(V)\cos(Abus)^{T}+Bdiag(V)sin(Abus)^{T}
\nonumber\\
&& +diag(V)diag(diag(G))))  \\
\label{eq4}
&& nondiag\frac{\partial P}{\partial V}= 
diag(V)G .* \cos(Abus) + diag(V)B .* \sin(Abus)   
\end{eqnarray}
Replace the diagnol elements of the (\ref{eq4}) with the elements of the    
(\ref{eq3}), we will get the complete $\partial P/\partial V$
\end{document}
```

And the result is:
[image]
We can see that the start positions of equation (1),(2) and equation (3),(4) are different. How can I solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: What does the operator `.*` do? Is it even an operator? Similarly, what does `.^{2}` do?

Comment: .* means it's not matrix multiplication, but element multiplication. For two 2*2 matrix A and B, the result C would be a 2*2 matrix with C(1,1)=a11*b11,C(1,2)=a12*b12,C(2,1)=a21*b21,C(2,2)=a22*b22

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replacing `eqnarray` by `align` the result is not perfectly aligned, but I looks like it is and I think nicer than with `eqnarray`.

Following Ian's suggestion `diag` and `nondiag` are declared math operators. Also parenthesis sizes has been adjusted.

After Mico's comment a new command `dotstar` has been declared. It's not clear for me what it does.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{txfonts}

\DeclareMathOperator{\diag}{diag}
\DeclareMathOperator{\nondiag}{nondiag}
\newcommand\dotstar{\mathbin{.*}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\label{eq1}
\diag\frac{\partial P}{\partial \theta} & = 
\diag\left(-\diag(V)\left[Gdiag(V)\sin(Abus)^{T}-B\diag(V)cos(Abus)^{T}\right]\right.
\nonumber\\
&\quad \left.-\diag(V).^{2}\diag\left(\diag(B)\right)\right)  \\
\label{eq2}
\nondiag\frac{\partial P}{\partial \theta} & = 
VV^{T}\dotstar G\dotstar\sin(Abus)-VV^{T}\dotstar B\dotstar\cos(Abus)   
\end{align}
Replace the diagnol elements of the (\ref{eq2}) with the elements of the                
(\ref{eq1}), we will get the complete $\partial P/\partial \theta$
\begin{align}
\label{eq3}
\diag\frac{\partial P}{\partial V} & =
\diag\left(G\diag(V)\cos(Abus)^{T}+B\diag(V)sin(Abus)^{T}\right.
\nonumber\\
&\quad +\Bigl.\diag(V)\diag\left(\diag(G)\right)\Bigr)  \\
\label{eq4}
\nondiag\frac{\partial P}{\partial V}&= 
\diag(V)G\dotstar\cos(Abus) + \diag(V)B\dotstar\sin(Abus)   
\end{align}
Replace the diagnol elements of the (\ref{eq4}) with the elements of the    
(\ref{eq3}), we will get the complete $\partial P/\partial V$
\end{document}
```

[image]

But if you want all equations perfectly aligned, insert the middle paragraph inside a `\intertext` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{txfonts}

\DeclareMathOperator{\diag}{diag}
\DeclareMathOperator{\nondiag}{nondiag}
\newcommand\dotstar{\mathbin{.*}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\label{eq1}
\diag\frac{\partial P}{\partial \theta} & = 
\diag\left(-\diag(V)\left[Gdiag(V)\sin(Abus)^{T}-B\diag(V)cos(Abus)^{T}\right]\right.
\nonumber\\
&\quad \left.-\diag(V).^{2}\diag\left(\diag(B)\right)\right)  \\
\label{eq2}
\nondiag\frac{\partial P}{\partial \theta} & = 
VV^{T}\dotstar G\dotstar\sin(Abus)-VV^{T}\dotstar B\dotstar\cos(Abus)   
%\end{align}
\intertext{Replace the diagnol elements of the (\ref{eq2}) with the elements of the                
(\ref{eq1}), we will get the complete $\partial P/\partial \theta$}
%\begin{align}
\label{eq3}
\diag\frac{\partial P}{\partial V} & =
\diag\left(G\diag(V)\cos(Abus)^{T}+B\diag(V)sin(Abus)^{T}\right.
\nonumber\\
&\quad +\Bigl.\diag(V)\diag\left(\diag(G)\right)\Bigr)  \\
\label{eq4}
\nondiag\frac{\partial P}{\partial V}&= 
\diag(V)G\dotstar\cos(Abus) + \diag(V)B\dotstar\sin(Abus)   
\end{align}
Replace the diagnol elements of the (\ref{eq4}) with the elements of the    
(\ref{eq3}), we will get the complete $\partial P/\partial V$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think you should also use `\DeclareMathOperator` for `diag` and `nondiag`.

Comment: Also, the typeset look of `.*` needs a bit of refinining.

Comment: @IanThompson I've followed your suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: @Mico I don't know what `.*` means. Which refinement do you suggest?

Comment: I'm not sure either what `.*` does, but I assume it's some kind of operator of type `mathbin`. Thus, I'd define the macro `\dotstar` iia `\newcommand\dotstar{\mathbin{.*}}` in the preamble and write `\dotstar` in the equations themselves. Probably not perfect, but almost certainly better than what's produced by writing `.*` directly.

Comment: @Mico I've applied your suggestion while waiting for OP's answer. Thank you.

Comment: @Mico@IanThompson Thank you. The operator I mean it's not matrix multiplication, but element multiplication. For two 2*2 matrix A and B, the result C would be a 2*2 matrix with C(1,1)=a11*b11,C(1,2)=a12*b12,C(2,1)=a21*b21,C(2,2)=a22*b22. I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: @user3391299 Looks like a [Hadamard product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)) which I didn't know until now. In this case, you can replace `\dotstar` with `\circ`.

Comment: I'm not sure you want to have `fleqn` that changes *all* displayed equations just for aligning some of them.

Comment: @egreg I've just copied `fleqn` from OP's code, I don't know what it does and don't remember to have ever used it.

Answer (score 2):

Never use `eqnarray` (see [eqnarray vs align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196/eqnarray-vs-align?s=12|1.1907))

Here the combination of `align` with `split` seems the best way to tackle the problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\diag}{diag}
\DeclareMathOperator{\nondiag}{nondiag}
\newcommand{\dotstar}{\mathbin{.{*}}}
\newcommand{\Abus}{\mathit{Abus}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\begin{split}
\diag\frac{\partial P}{\partial \theta} & = 
\diag\bigl(-\diag(V)[G \diag(V)\sin(\Abus)^{T}-B\diag(V)\cos(\Abus)^{T}]\\
&\qquad -\diag(V)^{2}\diag(\diag(B))\bigr)
\end{split}
\label{eq1} \\
\nondiag\frac{\partial P}{\partial \theta} & = 
VV^{T}\dotstar G\dotstar \sin(\Abus)-VV^{T}\dotstar B\cos(\Abus)   
\label{eq2}\\
\intertext{%
  By replacing the diagonal elements of the (\ref{eq2}) with the elements of
  equation~\eqref{eq1}, we will get the complete $\partial P/\partial \theta$}
\begin{split}
\diag\frac{\partial P}{\partial V} & =
  \diag\bigl(G\diag(V)\cos(\Abus)^{T}+B\diag(V)\sin(\Abus)^{T} \\
&\qquad +\diag(V)\diag(\diag(G))\bigr)
\end{split}
\label{eq3}\\
\nondiag\frac{\partial P}{\partial V}&= 
\diag(V)G\dotstar \cos(\Abus) + \diag(V)B\dotstar \sin(\Abus)   
\label{eq4}
\end{align}
By replacing the diagonal elements of equation~\eqref{eq4} with the elements of
equation~\eqref{eq3}, we will get the complete $\partial P/\partial V$

\end{document}
```

I replaced `txfonts` with `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` (the fonts for math are better and the packages are actively maintained).

If you add the `tbtags` option to `amsmath` the equation number will be aligned with the bottom line of the `split` parts.

I removed all `\left` and `\right` that served no purpose whatsoever (they just added unwanted horizontal space). Just a couple of `\big` pairs are needed.

[image]

Comment: how come there's not a `\big` on the outer parens in the first equation?  (those parens are outside `\big` pair of brackets, and the outer parens are `\big` in equation (3).)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Because I forgot to add them. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Using intertext in one align environment gets the alignment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\label{eq1}
& diag\frac{\partial P}{\partial \theta}= 
diag(-diag(V)[Gdiag(V)\sin(Abus)^{T}-Bdiag(V)cos(Abus)^{T}]
\nonumber\\
& -diag(V).^{2}diag(diag(B))))  \\
\label{eq2}
& nondiag\frac{\partial P}{\partial \theta}= 
VV^{T}.* G .* \sin(Abus) -VV^{T}.*B .* \cos(Abus)   
\intertext{Replace the diagnol elements of the (\ref{eq2}) with the     elements of the                
(\ref{eq1}), we will get the complete $\partial P/\partial \theta$}
\label{eq3}
&diag\frac{\partial P}{\partial V}=
diag(Gdiag(V)\cos(Abus)^{T}+Bdiag(V)sin(Abus)^{T}
   \nonumber\\
& +diag(V)diag(diag(G))))  \\
\label{eq4}
  & nondiag\frac{\partial P}{\partial V}= 
   diag(V)G .* \cos(Abus) + diag(V)B .* \sin(Abus)   
 \end{align}
    Replace the diagnol elements of the (\ref{eq4}) with the elements        of    the    
(\ref{eq3}), we will get the complete $\partial P/\partial V$
\end{document}
```